# Navigate to next page in ionic on-swipe-right

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I want to got to next page of the blog list when swipe right.

my view is:

```
<p on-swipe-right="onSwipeRight()" ng-bind-html="blog.content"> {{blog.content}}</p>
```

and controller function is:

```
 $scope.onSwipeRight = function () {
    // Do whatever here to manage swipe left
    //alert('Right swipped');
    .state('lab-components', {url: '/blog/:id'})
  }
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand what this means:

```
.state('lab-components', {url: '/blog/:id'})
```

If you want to move from one state to the other you can use [$state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#state-1) and specifically [$state.go()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options).

It needs to be injected in your controller before you can used it:

```
.controller('homeController', function($scope, $state) {

    $scope.onSwipeRight = function (id) {
        $state.go('blogdetail', { blogId: id });
    }

})
```

As you can see I've passed an `id` to my `onSwipeRight` method so I can use it to go to the other state passing it as a parameter.

```
<p on-swipe-right="onSwipeRight(blog.id)">{{blog.content}}</p>
```

Probably you need to change your state as well:

```
  $stateProvider.state('blogdetail', {
      url: '/blogdetail/:blogId',
      templateUrl: 'blogdetail.html',
      controller: 'blogdetailController',
  });
```

As you can see I've used `:blogId` as a [parameter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#basic-parameters).

It must match the name we've used here:

```
$state.go('blogdetail', { blogId: id });
```

and if you want to read that parameter in your `blogdetail` controller:

```
.controller('blogdetailController', function($scope, $stateParams){

    var id = $stateParams.blogId;

});
```

`$stateParams` service will help you with that. It must be injected.

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jVjvDbZtpsOehfg7wsFa?p=preview) might help you to understand how things work.

Comment: Feel free to comment, accept or upvote the answer. Cheers.